# After initializing git clone ASP.NET Core MVC app marked as unloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

[image: What opening visual studio gives me after clone]

What am i doing wrong here and how can I prevent this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that I normally do to overcome it.

1. Try reloading the `webproj.csproj` files and check if any reference is
   missing.
2. check for the version in which the code was built and the version you are using.
3. Open the web project part directly. For that you first need to remove the existing we project and re add using the add existing
   project.